# insert image in crystal report

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

i need to set logo of company according to the title of it..so along with company title want to send image path and set the image accordingly...
My motot is to set image dynamically..but not from database...
Read the ideas.nd coverted image in byte[]..but i am not able to send it along with parameter...and wat parameter shall i take on report for displaying it???

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if Crystal Report accept byte[] as a parameter.
Do you have the path of the images, if so I guess you could try to create a report with an image on it, then right click on the image and select ->"Format Graphic" -> On the "Picture" tab, you can set the "Picture Location",
You can try to put the Image file path on the "Picture Location" properties.

Please correct me if my concept is wrong